# Show pdf in iframe inside uiwebview IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, uiwebview

I am experimenting some issues while trying to display a pdf in an iframe. On android it works fine but on ios, I have problems because you cannot scroll the pdf. You just see what appears in screen and not anymore. If you try to move the screen you see white. I am loading a webpage inside a uiwebview on ios.

This is a bucle in which I load many pages with many pdfs. So that is why there are a val.id... on id and urls.

This is my code in html:

```
<div data-theme="e" data-role="page" id="PDFSHOW'+ val.id_boletin + '" data-url="PAGE' + val.id_boletin + '"> 
                                             <div data-theme="f" data-role="header">
                                                 <h1>'+ val.title +'</h1> 
                                                 <a href="#linktoreturn" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
                                             </div>
                                             <div data-role="content"> 
                                                 <iframe class="testIframe" src="'+val.link+'" style="width: 600px; height: 5000px; border: medium none;visibility: visible;" > 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                      
                    )
```

I don't know what to do because I always find out that this is the correct way to display it.Any idea